# how to import matplotlib in python

Tags: python, module, matplotlib, graph-theory

I am new to python and I am working on a graph problem and I want  to draw this graph to have a better understanding of it. I learnt that matplotlib module is supposed to be imported for this but I dont know how to add  it to the project.(I am a java developer and It is pretty much like adding jar to your classpath)

When I try doing

```
import matplotlib
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.7rc1-py2.7.egg/networkx/drawing/nx‌​_pylab.py", line 114, in draw
    raise ImportError("Matplotlib required for draw()")
ImportError: Matplotlib required for draw()
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

Can anyone help me with that?Do I need to download anything to make it run as in the module?

Comment: I recommend you to take a look in the source code of [examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/index.html)

Comment: Please follow the [user guide](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/index.html)

Comment: Windows, Linux, OSX? What is the name of your python file? You must help people to reproduce your error, otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: have you download and installed matplotlib?

Answer (score 20):

**module: `new`**

As David Robinson points out in a comment on another answer you may have posted an incomplete error message, in which case it is possible that the inbuilt module `new` is being shadowed by `new.py` in the `gis` module. - if that is the case the [suggested fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790233/unable-to-import-matplotlib-python-2-7-windows-7) is to rename the `gis` version.

**Incomplete Matplotlib install**

Alternatively, given your output you may be trying to import `networkx` and you don't seem to have `matplotlib` (correctly) installed.

Could you make sure that `matplotlib` **is** correctly installed, either if you're on *Ubuntu* by using

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

or if you prefer `pip` or `easy_install`,

```
pip install matplotlib
```

or

```
easy_install matplotlib
```

Comment: The `pip` command helped on Windows, since it is available after installing Python.

Answer (score 5):

If you use **windows**,
Open the command prompt and type

> python -m pip install matplotlib

For **linux** users ,
 type this

> sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem solved - not only for this package - using instead of pip install :

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

work on the cv virtual environment and then use the command
and execute your script in the virtual environment using
source ~/.profile
workon cv