# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pip

I'm trying to run a python program that requires matplotlib, which I've already installed via pip. I am running Python 3.6 locally on my Mac, with my .bash_profile updated to reflect this. The import line in question is as seen below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Below is the error message I see, as you can figure out from the subject line:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

And here's what I see if I try `pip install matplotlib`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
```

I've referenced a few other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815538/how-to-import-matplotlib-in-python), but without much luck. Am I overlooking an answer that I just didn't follow through with, or could it be something else? Your time is appreciated.